# SQL Alchemy: Relationship with grandson

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I'm building a SQL Alchemy structure with three different levels of objects; for example, consider a simple database to store information about some blogs: there are some `Blog` object, some `Post` object and some `Comment` objects. Each `Post` belongs to a `Blog` and each `Comment` belongs to a `Post`. Using `backref` I can automatically have the list of all `Post`s belonging to a `Blog` and similarly for `Comment`s.

I drafted a [skeleton for such a structure](http://pastebin.com/dJgP9rNm).

What I would like to do now is to have directly in `Blog` an array of all the `Comment`s belonging to that `Blog`. I've tried a few approaches, but they don't work or even make SQL Alchemy cry in ways I can't fix. I'd think that mine is quite a frequent need, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Colud someone suggest me how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Never heard of such a relationship in SQL. You likely have to perform a loop internally on your own or you perform an explicit join operation inside your blog implementation....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use an [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html)

```
class Blog(Base):

    comments = association_proxy('posts', 'comments')
```

Comment: I didn't try because I'm in the need anymore, but from the docs apparently association proxies should be the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [join](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins):

```
comments = session.query(Comment).join(Post).filter(Post.blog == b1).all()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm searching something different: I'd like to add `comments` directly as a field of class Blog, in order to access it the same way I'd do for the backref `tasks`. In other words, I don't want the line that executes the query, but I'd like to bind some field of the class to a query that gets executed each time the field is accessed (like, in general, `relatioship` does). I [tried to implement this](http://pastebin.com/wKmYq77p), but there is an error I can't understand. Compare lines 46 and 77.